# Maximum Entropy Distribution with Asymptotic

Tags: optimization, entropy, constraints

Set $P(x)$ as probability distribution function, which satisfies(constraints)

- $x\in[0,1]$
- $P(x)\ge 0$, $\int^1_0P(x)dx=1$
- $P(x)\rightarrow x^2$ while $x\rightarrow 0$
- $P(x)=P(1-x)$

Then, how to find the maximum entropy distribution of it? In other words, does there exist a form of **smooth** function $P(x)$ such that $\Lambda(x):=-\int^{1}_0 P(x)\ln P(x)dx$ is the maximum value, and what is it?

---

One came up with the idea when meeting an other question related with it, where $P(x)$ satisfies

- $x\in S$
- $\int_S f_i(x)P(x)dx=\alpha_i$

The maximum entropy distribution with constraints [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Proof_in_the_case_of_equality_constraints)
$$P(x)=\exp \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \lambda_{j} f_{j}(x)\right)$$
where $\lambda_j$ can be calculated with the constraints.

---

But how to solve my problem especially the $3\text{rd}$ condition? And the $4\text{th}$ condition may be useless as we can transform the interval to $[0,1/2]$ by symmetry.

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there does not exist such a maximum entropy distribution.

As you note, the fourth condition just reduces to studying probability distributions on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$; for simplicity, I will just ignore it.

The maximum entropy distribution on $[0,1]$ is well-known to be the uniform, which has entropy $0$.  But now consider the distribution $$P_\epsilon(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}}{1-\epsilon} & \epsilon\leq x\leq1 \\
x^2 & 0\leq x\leq\epsilon
\end{cases}$$  This has entropy \begin{align*}
-\int_0^1{P_\epsilon(x)\ln{\!(P_\epsilon(x))}\,dx}&=-\int_0^{\epsilon}{2x^2\ln{(x)}\,dx}-\left(1-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}\right)\ln{\!\left(\frac{1-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}}{1-\epsilon}\right)} \\
&=-\epsilon^2(2\ln{\!(\epsilon)}-1)-\left(1-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}\right)\ln{\!\left(\frac{1-\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}}{1-\epsilon}\right)} \\
&=-\epsilon+\epsilon^2\left(\frac{1}{2}-2\ln{\!(\epsilon)}\right)+o(\epsilon^2) \\
&\to0
\end{align*} as $\epsilon\to0^+$.  Thus the supremum of entropy over distributions satisfying (1-3) is $0$, which we already know is attained only for the uniform distribution.  And the uniform distribution fails to satisfy (3).

Comment: Thank you. But how if we add a condition that **$P(x)$ is smooth**? For example, assume $P(x)=x^2\cdot q(x)$, where $q(x)\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ and $q(x)$ is smooth, like $e^{-x^2}$ and so on. Can we construct a function like yours as well?

Comment: @SHBooKP: Sure; just take $0<\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2<1$, and pick a smooth function that is $1$ on $[0,\epsilon_1]$ and $0$ on $[\epsilon_2,1]$.  For $1\gg\epsilon_2\gg\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1$, you get the same result.